# Como passar objetos entre controllers no MVC utilizando POO

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Basicamente, eu preciso que ser o login for bem sucedido salvar o nome de usuário em uma variável e utilizar-lá em outro controller.

Model.php:

```
   public function login($email, $password) {
    session_start();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password= :password;";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    $parameters = array(':email' => $email, ':password' => $password);
    $query->execute($parameters);
    $rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    if($rows > 0) {
        header ("Location: " . URL . "home");
    } else {
        exit ('Email or password incorrect');
    }
}
```

Controller.php

```
  public function login() {
    if (isset($_POST['login_submit']) AND isset($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $this->model->login($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Controller para controller então seria HMVC, no MVC clássico é somente um controller. Mostre o que tem ou qual FW está usando para facilitar.

Comment: Estou usando uma framework que eu mesmo desenvolvi, não posso postar ela aqui pois é um projeto privado.

Comment: Certo, mas que informação você quer passar e de 'onde para onde'?

Comment: Eu quero passar o nome do usuário que está dentro de uma função para outra função.

Comment: Então não é controller? Geralmente o controller invoca uma classe - componente - responsável pela autenticação do usuário e as informações transitam facilmente. Sem saber o que tem não dá pra auxiliar muito. Mostre um exemplo genérico pelo menos.

Comment: Acabei de editar o code (Code do model.php): Caso o login esteja certo, passar o nome do usuário para dentro de uma variável e usar-lá em outro controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não foi explicito mas parece que você quer que seja mandado por `session`. Sendo assim você pode simplesmente setar na sessão e pegar de volta  no outro controle.

```
<?php
// declaração da classe Pessoa
class Pessoa {
    public $nome;
}


// No Controller que envia os parametros
session_start();
$joao = new Pessoa();
$joao->nome = "João";
$_SESSION['pessoa'] = $joao;


// No Controller que recebe os dados
session_start();
$joao = $_SESSION['pessoa'];
print_r($joao);
```

Ou se quiser padronizar isso e jogar no paradigma de orientação a objetos

```
<?php

// controller que envia 
$joao = new Pessoa();
$joao->nome = "João";
SessionUtils::setPropriedade('pessoa', $joao);

// controller que recebe 
$joao = SessionUtils::getPropriedadeLimpar('pessoa');
print_r($joao);


// declaração da classe Pessoa
class Pessoa {
    public $nome;
}

// classe util para a sessão
class SessionUtils {

    private static $BASE_PROPRIEDADES = "props";

    /**
     * Pega uma propriedade da sessão 
     * @return a propriedade ou null se não existir
     */
    public static function getPropriedade($nome){
        self::configurarSessao();
        $sessao = self::getSessao();
        return @$sessao[$nome];
    }

    /**
     * Pega uma propriedade da sessão e depois a exclui da mesma
     * @return a propriedade ou null se não existir
     */
    public static function getPropriedadeLimpar($nome){
        self::configurarSessao();
        $sessao = self::getSessao();
        $valor  = @$sessao[$nome];
        self::setPropriedade($nome, null);
        return $valor;
    }

    /**
     * Seta uma propriedade na sessão
     */
    public static function setPropriedade($nome, $valor){
        self::configurarSessao();
        $_SESSION[self::$BASE_PROPRIEDADES][$nome] = $valor;
    }

    /**
     * Configura a sessão para guardar os itens
     */
    private static function configurarSessao(){
        if(!isset($_SESSION)){
            session_start();
        }
        if(!self::getSessao() || !is_array(self::getSessao())){
            self::setSessao(array());
        }
    }

    private static function getSessao(){
        return $_SESSION[self::$BASE_PROPRIEDADES];
    }

    private static function setSessao($valor){
        $_SESSION[self::$BASE_PROPRIEDADES] = $valor;
    }
}
```